# How to insert another CSS in const and calling from another const in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have `div` with `className` and I want to apply CSS to it as `display:none` which can be easily done by separate css file attached to my component. Now, when I click on the function of `const`, I want to apply another CSS within the one `const`.

It is calling like this:

```
const syncData = () => {
    displayyYes();
}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
const displayYes = () => {
   table__upper__section:{
   display: 'block'
}
}

<div className="table__upper__section">
   <button onClick={syncData}>Click me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what you are trying to do. React renders your current state, and `syncData` is a side effect. To change state value you can update it inside side effect (in event handler or function that you pass inside `useEffect` hook).

Now to the question. You can get your connected stylesheets and delete and insert rules, but I strongly advise you not to do it.  If you 100% sure you want to go this route, you will have to [get all your stylesheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets), [find the one with rule you need](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet), delete old rule and insert new one.

If you want "react way" to show or hide something, use state.

Option 1, with stylesheet and two classes:

```js
let [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

function hideSomething() {
  setVisible(false);
}
let className = visible ? "visible" : "invisible";
return (
  <>
    <div className={className}>Something to hide</div>
    <button onClick={hideSomething}>Hide</button>
  </>
);
```

Option 2, with inline styles:

```js
let [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

function hideSomething() {
  setVisible(false);
}
return (
  <>
    <div style={{display: visible ? 'block' : 'none'}>Something to hide</div>
    <button onClick={hideSomething}>Hide</button>
  </>
);
```

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for replying. But what I'm trying to do is I need to hide table__upper__section initially on page load. But when I do some actions like onClick on List or Button, then I'm calling a second const which sets table__upper__section css property to display:none

Comment: You are calling functions, not variables (but variable hold your function, so you are partially right). And examples above can used to initially hide something and then show, or vice versa. So, let's say, you have some component with state variable `tableHeaderHidden` which value is `true`. When something happens, you set your state variable to `false` and content appears. It is better to use two classes and switch them around (or to have one special class for hiding things). It is not really good practice to do something with  attached stylesheets. It can get too complicated very fast.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for this wonderful explanation. Actually, I'm learning React. So. I came up with this doubt. So, once again thanks a ton.